# Implemention of multiple pipes in C

Tags: c

I am doing a bash-like command intereptor and I started the implemention of multiple pipes and reddirections.

At the moment I have this code :

```
int execute_pipe(t_comm *com, t_struct *tool, char **env)
{
  int   pipefd[2 * tool->nbr_pipe];
  int   i;
  int   j;
  pid_t pid;

  i = -1;
  //pipefd = xmalloc(sizeof(int) * tool->nbr_pipe * 2);
  while (++i != tool->nbr_pipe)
    pipe(pipefd + i * 2);
  j = 0;
  while (com != NULL)
    {
      pid = fork();
      if (pid == 0)
    {
      if (com->next != NULL)
        dup2(pipefd[j + 1], 1);
      if (j != 0)
        dup2(pipefd[j - 2], 0);
      i = -1;
      while (++i < 2 * tool->nbr_pipe)
        close(pipefd[i]);
      printf("%s\n", com->argv[0]);
      execve(com->argv[0], com->argv, env);
    }
      com = com->next;
      j = j + 2;
    }
  i = -1;
  while (++i < 2 * tool->nbr_pipe)
    close(pipefd[i]);
  i = -1;
  while (++i != tool->nbr_pipe + 1)
    wait(NULL);
}
```

But this don't seems to work. When i launch something like "ls | cat -e" it's just displaying an normal ls and then i have to do a control C to come back to my prompt.
Have you got an idea where this could come from ?

And sorry for the indenting, Stack overflow seems to not like emacs tabulations...

Comment: It is hard to tell considering we have no clue about what are `com`, `tool` or `env` and how they are used. As a side note, your use of `pipe` is a bit hacky: you could deal with an array with `nbr_pip` elements of type `int pipefd[2]`

Comment: What have you done in the way of instrumenting your code?  You should protect yourself against failure to `execve()`, but that isn't the cause of your immediate trouble.  You should use `for` loops instead of the whacky `while` loops — but I think you'll end up telling us that you're not allowed to use `for` loops (which is whacky, but unavoidable if you are subject to the constraints I suspect you are subject to). You should detect which processes exit and what their exit status was. Bear in mind that if you have background processes running, they could finish while the current pipeline runs.